# Jquery Reference in javascript File

Tags: jquery-plugins

Following is a demo for image magnification on a web page

http://jdbartlett.com/loupe/

I tried to use the open source code in building this into a plugin which could be installed as a script in a browser so that it could work for any website that is viewed through it(the browser)

The code sample has few demos and two jquery files which are to be referred in order to use the code

what i need to do is to develop another .js file and include(somehow) the required jquery libraries

I tried the following code

```
function

 include(filename, onload) {

var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

 var script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = filename;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (script.readyState) {
            if (script.readyState === 'complete' || script.readyState === 'loaded') {
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                onload();
            }
        }

        else {
            onload();
        }
    };
    head.appendChild(script);

}
include(path + 'imagemagnifier/jquery.loupe.js');


$('img').loupe();
```

where loupe is a function defined in the file that was included and I guess this is where the actual problem lies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second paramer to call the code that you want to run when the file is loaded.

```
include(path + 'imagemagnifier/jquery.loupe.js', function(){ $('img').loupe(); });
```

But since it is jQuery, why not use [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)?

```
jQuery.getScript(path + 'imagemagnifier/jquery.loupe.js', function(){ $('img').loupe(); });
```

Comment: The thing is the with the help of the above code i ma not able to even get the file referenced so the $('img').loupe();
also do not work

Comment: looking at the net tb in your console, i the request a 404?

Comment: just solved the reference issue
Was some path problem :)

Now the problem summary is.........
I have this imagine zoom jQuery plugin, which zooms an images through the following code: $('demo').loupe
Instead of using the plugin this way, I want this plugin to look for any img elements inside body and magnify them
i.e I would only need to include this file in my page and it would do the rest
How can this be done
?

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the jQuery function `$.getScript(scriptName, callback)`?

It will load any script file (internally or externally hosted) whenever called. If you're already using jQuery, it won't really add any excess overhead, and you don't have to worry about messy appending of the HTML.

Read more at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/